Redux State update will not cause a re-render when changed from within a custom hook
I have set up a Redux slice for which I've created a custom wrapper-hook (I hate the "{ type: x, payload: y }" syntax :p)
Here's the slice:
// polycanvas.ts (Redux)

export const polycanvas = createSlice({
  name: 'polycanvas',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // Arcs
    addArc: (state, action: PayloadAction<Arc>) => {
      if (state.arcs.length < state.settings.arc.maxArcs) {
        state.arcs = [...state.arcs, action.payload];
      } else {
        throw(`Number of arcs exceeds the maximum. (max: ${state.settings.arc.maxArcs}, got: ${state.arcs.length})`);
      }
    },
    removeArc: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      if (state.arcs[action.payload]) {
        state.arcs = state.arcs.filter((_, index) => index != action.payload);
      } else {
        throw(`Tried removing arc at index ${action.payload}. No such arc exists.`);
      }
    },
    setArcs: (state, action: PayloadAction<Arc[]>) => {
      if (action.payload.length < state.settings.arc.maxArcs) {
        state.arcs = action.payload;
      } else {
        throw(`Number of arcs exceeds the maximum. (max: ${state.settings.arc.maxArcs}, got: ${action.payload.length})`);
      }
    },

    //... other stuff
  }
});

export const usePolycanvas = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const arcs = useAppSelector(state => state.polycanvas.arcs);
  const arc = {
    addArc: (arc: Arc) =>
      dispatch(polycanvas.actions.addArc(arc)),
    removeArc: (index: number) =>
      dispatch(polycanvas.actions.removeArc(index)),
    setArcs: (arcs: Arc[]) =>
      dispatch(polycanvas.actions.setArcs(arcs)),
    
    //... other stuff
  }

  return { arc, arcs };
}

As far as I'm concerned, this is correct Redux usage.
In my React Component:
// Polycanvas.tsx (React Component)

export default () => {
  const { arc, arcs } = usePolycanvas();

  const makeArcs = (arcCount: number): void => {
    const _arcs = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arcCount; i++) {
      const velocity = (4 * Math.PI * (settings.speed.loops - i)) / settings.speed.timeframeSeconds;
      _arcs.push({
        color: { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255, a: 0.3 },
        velocity,
        nextImpactTime: calculateImpactTime(startTime, velocity),
      });
    }
    arc.setArcs(_arcs);
  }


  React.useEffect(() => {
    makeArcs(10);
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(arcs);
  }, [arcs]);

  return (<canvas ref={ref} className="polycanvas" />);
  // Ref is used for drawing to the canvas - not relevant in this example
}

Console only prints [] , nothing actually renders unless I write to a file and Vite does its HMR magic.
Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Is this behavior not supported by Redux?
EDIT: Added CodeSandbox demo.

"As far as I'm concerned, this is correct Redux usage." - It's not. Either mutate the state or compute and return a new state object... never both. Also due to Javascript closures, the arcs state won't have updated in the useEffect hook callback after makeArcs call when you try to console log it. Do console.log(arcs); in a separate effect with a dependency on the selected arcs state.

@DrewReese Correct about the return - thank you! However, none of which you've suggested has helped. I've updated the question body to reflect the changes.

"nothing actually renders unless I write to a file and Vite does its HMR magic." - What are you trying to render? As far as I can tell nothing of the Redux and Polycanvas  code you have renders anything but an empty canvas, e.g. <canvas ref={ref} className="polycanvas" />. Although a bit odd I don't see any overt issue in the code you shared in your post. Is this a complete [mcve]? Is state => state.polycanvas.arcs the correct value? Think you could create a running codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

@DrewReese My bad! Added demo.

The reducers in your sandbox are still incorrectly reassigning the state value and/or mutating and returning the state value.
See Direct State Mutation for further details.
export const polycanvas = createSlice({
  name: 'polycanvas',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // Arcs
    addArc: (state, action: PayloadAction<Arc>) => {
      if (state.arcs.length < state.settings.arc.maxArcs) {
        // ERROR: don't re-assign the state value
        // state = {
        //   ...state,
        //   arcs: [...state.arcs, action.payload]
        // };

        // OK: mutate state directly
        state.arcs.push(action.payload);
      } else {
        throw(`Number of arcs exceeds the maximum. (max: ${state.settings.arc.maxArcs}, got: ${state.arcs.length})`);
      }
    },
    removeArc: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      if (state.arcs[action.payload]) {
        state.arcs = state.arcs.filter((_, index) => index != action.payload);
      } else {
        throw(`Tried removing arc at index ${action.payload}. No such arc exists.`);
      }
    },
    setArcs: (state, action: PayloadAction<Arc[]>) => {
      if (action.payload.length < state.settings.arc.maxArcs) {
        // ERROR: don't re-assign the state value
        // state = {
        //   ...state,
        //   arcs: action.payload
        // }

        // OK: mutate state directly
        state.arcs = action.payload;
      } else {
        throw(`Number of arcs exceeds the maximum. (max: ${state.settings.arc.maxArcs}, got: ${action.payload.length})`);
      }
    },
    // Settings
    settings_setLoops: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.settings.speed.loops = action.payload;

      // ERROR: don't mutate & return state
      // return state;

      // Also OK, return entirely new state value
      // return {
      //   ...state,
      //   settings: {
      //     ...state.settings,
      //     speed: {
      //       ...state.settings.speed,
      //       loops: action.payload,
      //     },
      //   },
      // };
    },
    settings_setTimeframeSeconds: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.settings.speed.timeframeSeconds = action.payload;

      // ERROR: don't re-assign the state value
      // return state;
    },
    settings_setMaxArcs: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.settings.arc.maxArcs = action.payload;

      // ERROR: don't re-assign the state value
      // return state;
    },
    settings_setArcDistance: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.settings.arc.distance = action.payload;

      // ERROR: don't re-assign the state value
      // return state;
    }
  }
});

The additional issue is that the PolyCanvas is editing/setting properties on a canvas and canvas context ctx variable, but these variables are re-declared each render cycle.
I suggest the following refactor:
useAnimationFrame: Update signature to consume a dependency array.
import React from "react";

export default (callback: (...args: any[]) => any, deps: any[] = []) => {
  // Use useRef for mutable variables that we want to persist
  // without triggering a re-render on their change
  const requestRef = React.useRef<number>();
  const previousTimeRef = React.useRef<number>();
  
  const animate = (time: number) => {
    if (previousTimeRef.current != undefined) {
      const deltaTime = time - previousTimeRef.current;
      callback(deltaTime)
    }
    previousTimeRef.current = time;
    requestRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    requestRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    return () => cancelAnimationFrame(requestRef.current!);
  }, deps);
}

Poluycanvas: Move the ctx and canvas variables outside the component (or use React refs) so they are stable references, and pass the selected arcs state as a dependency for the useAnimationFrame hook call.
import React from "react";
import { Arc, usePolycanvas } from "../redux/polycanvas";
import useAnimationFrame from "../hooks/useAnimationFrame";

type Coords2D = {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

type Canvas = {
  center: Coords2D;
  start: Coords2D;
  end: Coords2D;
  length: number;

  strokeStyle: CanvasRenderingContext2D['strokeStyle'];
  lineWidth: CanvasRenderingContext2D['lineWidth'];
}

let ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D | null;
let canvas: Canvas;

export default () => {
  const canvasRef = React.createRef<HTMLCanvasElement>();
  const startTime = performance.now();

  const { arc, arcs, settings } = usePolycanvas();

  const calculateImpactTime = (currentImpactTime: number, velocity: number) => {
    return currentImpactTime + (Math.PI / velocity) * 1000;
  }
    
  const makeArcs = (arcCount: number): void => {
    const _arcs = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arcCount; i++) {
      const velocity = (4 * Math.PI * (settings.speed.loops - i)) / settings.speed.timeframeSeconds;
      _arcs.push({
        color: { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255, a: 0.3 },
        velocity,
        nextImpactTime: calculateImpactTime(startTime, velocity),
      });
    }
    arc.setArcs(_arcs);
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    makeArcs(10);

    if (canvasRef.current) {
      ctx = canvasRef.current?.getContext("2d");

      canvasRef.current.width = canvasRef.current.clientWidth;
      canvasRef.current.height = canvasRef.current.clientHeight;

      const center: Coords2D = {
        x: canvasRef.current.width / 2,
        y: canvasRef.current.height / 2
      };
      const start: Coords2D = {
        x: 0,
        y: canvasRef.current.height / 2
      };
      const end: Coords2D = {
        x: canvasRef.current.width,
        y: canvasRef.current.height / 2
      };
      const length = end.x;

      canvas = {
        center, start, end, length,
        strokeStyle: `rgba(255, 255,
          255, 0.3)`,
        lineWidth: 1,
      }
    }
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(arcs);
  }, [arcs]);
    
  const drawArcs = () => {
    if (canvas && ctx) {
      const initialArcRadius = canvas.length * settings.arc.distance;
      const spacing = (canvas.length / 2 - initialArcRadius) / arcs.length;

      arcs.forEach((arc: Arc, index: number) => {
        
        if (ctx) {
          const radius = initialArcRadius + (index * spacing);
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(canvas.center.x, canvas.center.y, radius, Math.PI * 2, 0);

          ctx.strokeStyle = `rgba(${arc.color.r}, ${arc.color.g},
            ${arc.color.b}, ${arc.color.a})`;

          ctx.lineWidth = ctx.lineWidth;

          ctx.stroke();
        }
      });
    }
  }

  const clearCanvas = () => {
    if (ctx) {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    }
  };
    
  useAnimationFrame(() => {
    clearCanvas();
    drawArcs();
  }, [arcs]);

  return (
    <canvas ref={canvasRef} className="poly-canvas" />
  );
}


In my hurry, I incorrectly implemented the code in my program in the demo. However, I don't mean to be rude, but modifying the code on the demo to reflect the body of my question, the issue still doesn't seem to be resolved.

@stealing_society Ok, I think I've found the canvas rendering/synchronization issue. Check the answer update.
